# Getting all rows where a key occurs only once among all columns

Tags: mysql, sql

```
column1 column2 
A       1
A       2
A       3
B       1
C       1
C       2
D       1
```

I want a query that prints

```
column1 column2 
B       1
D       1
```

Since B and D occur just once in the table.

I have tried queries like `select column1 from table group by column1 having count(column1)=1` but this didn't work.

Comment: Show complete CREATE TABLE script.

Comment: I don't see why the create table is relevant

Comment: *but this didn't work* ??? error? show complete error message. Wrong output? show it and describe what is incorrect.

Comment: There was a much bigger table which I was using and there were rows which had multiple key occurrences that were appearing In the result

Comment: "There was a much bigger table which I was using and there were rows"... do you mean the data in the question doesn't show the problem?

Comment: It does. Maybe the query that I mentioned works for the data I have here, but for some reason it isn't working for the much bigger table I am describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT column1
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY column1
HAVING count(column1)=1
```

Hope this works in your case

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need in this:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
JOIN (
    SELECT column1
    FROM table t2
    GROUP BY column1
    HAVING COUNT(column1)=1
    ) t3 USING (column1)
```

Comment: what is t3 here?

Comment: @SwastikUdupa This is an alias.